# BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged Invoked From Another Class Not Updating Progress Bar

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

**UPDATED With Improved Detail Source Code**

**Context:**
I am building a Winforms application using an MVC architecture.   My View contains a Search Button, a ProgressBar, and BackgroundWorker control.

Events

```
        this.wrkBackgroundSearch.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        this.wrkBackgroundSearch.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        this.wrkBackgroundSearch.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.wrkBackgroundSearch_DoWork);
        this.wrkBackgroundSearch.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.wrkBackgroundSearch_RunWorkerCompleted);
        this.wrkBackgroundSearch.ProgressChanged += new System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventHandler(this.wrkBackgroundSearch_ProgressChanged);
```

The BackgroundWorker (wrkBackgrounSearch)'s DoWork event:

```
private void wrkBackgroundSearch_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BatchReaderController backgroundCnt = new BatchReaderController();
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        IDictionary<int, object> args = (IDictionary<int, object>)e.Argument;
        //Breaking the arg list down
        Int32 docType                       = (Int32)args[docTypeArgKey];
        Int32 chosenSearchElement           = (Int32)args[searchElementArgKey];
        Int32 environment                   = (Int32)args[environmentArgKey];

        try
        {
            e.Result = backgroundCnt.PerformSearch(docType, chosenSearchElement, environment, criteria, isFilenameSearch, worker, totalFileCount, directoriesToSearch, fileNameMask, xPath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.ShowError(ex.Message, "Error while searching", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
}
```

I also have this event:

```
private void wrkBackgroundSearch_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    prgSearchProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Finally, inside the custom BatchReaderController object's PerformSearch method I have PerformXPathSearch method.  (This is the I/O-intensive operation that runs in the background, and is supposed to provide async updates.)

```
private IList<BatchFileData> PerformXPathSearch(IList<String> uncPaths, Int32 docType, Int32 searchElement, String searchCriteria, BackgroundWorker worker, Int64 totalFileCount, String inputFileMask, String inputXPathQuery)
    {
        Int64 numberFilesSearched = 0;
        IList<BatchFileData> searchResults = new List<BatchFileData>();

        //Validate inputs

        //Look in each drive that was input
        foreach (String networkPath in uncPaths)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir;
            FileInfo[] files = null;
            try
            {
                dir = new DirectoryInfo(networkPath);
            }
            catch (Exception ae)
            {
                throw new Exception("Bad directory path: " + ae.Message, ae);
            }


            if (!dir.Exists)
            {
                continue;
            }

            try
            {
                files = dir.GetFiles(inputFileMask, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            }
            catch (Exception ae)
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid filename mask: " + filenameMask, ae);
            }

            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                numberFilesSearched++;
                Boolean shouldOpenFile = DetermineWhetherToOpenFile(file.CreationTime);
                XmlDocument xmlDoc;
                XPathNavigator nav;
                XPathNavigator searchNode;
                DataSet xmlAsDataSet;

                if (!shouldOpenFile)
                {
                    Int32 percentComplete = CalculatePercentComplete(totalFileCount, numberFilesSearched);
                    worker.ReportProgress(percentComplete, searchResults.Count);
                    continue;
                }

                try
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = file.OpenRead())
                    {
                        xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                        xmlDoc.Load(fs);
                    }
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
                {
                    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Unable to read path to file: " + file.FullName, uae);
                }
                nav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();

                try
                {
                    searchNode = nav.SelectSingleNode(inputXPathQuery);
                }
                catch (ArgumentException ae)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Argument Exception performing node select: " + xpathQuery, ae);
                }
                catch (XPathException xpe)
                {
                    throw new XPathException("Xpath error while performing node select: " + xpathQuery, xpe);
                }

                //If search results returns criteria success, add this data set to the list for display.
                if (searchNode != null)
                {
                    //Capture data for later processing
                }

                Int32 percentageComplete = CalculatePercentComplete(totalFileCount, numberFilesSearched);
                worker.ReportProgress(percentageComplete, searchResults.Count);
            }
        }

        return searchResults;
    }
```

Calculate Percent Complete

```
private Int32 CalculatePercentComplete(Int64 totalFileCount, Int64 numFoldersSearched)
    {
        Int32 percentAsInt;
        float searchPercent;

        searchPercent = numFoldersSearched / totalFileCount;

        try
        {
            percentAsInt = Convert.ToInt32(searchPercent);
        }
        catch (OverflowException oe)
        {
            throw new OverflowException("Error getting percent complete: " + oe.Message, oe);
        }

        if ((percentAsInt < 0) || (percentAsInt > 100))
        {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Invalid percentage: " + percentAsInt);
        }

        return percentAsInt;
    }
```

**Problem:**
When testing, my ProgressBar does not receive the updates, even though while stepping through the code, the ProgressChanged event IS being fired.

I have also tried several iterations of the following, after checking threads on StackOverflow, within the ProgressChanged event:

```
private void wrkBackgroundSearch_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    prgSearchProgress.Invoke(new PerformProgrssUpdate(this.DisplaySearchProgress),
        new object[]{e.ProgressPercentage});
    //if (prgSearchProgress.InvokeRequired)
    //{
    //    prgSearchProgress.Invoke();
    //}
}

private void DisplaySearchProgress(Int32 percentComplete)
{
    prgSearchProgress.Value = percentComplete;
}

public delegate void PerformProgrssUpdate(Int32 percentComplete);
```

Note the commented-out attempt of another solution.   The search operation will complete successfully, and when the search operation is completed, the ProgressBar control has its value updated to (1/n)% complete, as the search finishes.

**Question**
How do I make this work, such that when my Controller performs the I/O-intense search, the Progress Bar in my view is updated appropriately, so that the user knows some function is being executed?

Comment: Is the displaysearhprogress called on the UI thread? You can check that while debugging

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: I don't see it anywhere in your example code.... did you subscribe to the ProgressChanged event

Comment: I'm not buying, particularly since it actually updates.  Occam's razor says that you are simply calculating the progress percentage wrong.  As posted, the worker.ReportProgress call in PerformSearch() method should pass 100 since it is the last operation.

Comment: Btw you set the result in 1 function call as i can see. I dont see any loop for your progress updates. With the code you posted, the progresschanged is fired once

Comment: What @Hans means is that rhe most likely cause is a rounding error inside `DetermineCompletionPercentAsInt()`. And @sievajet also has a point. So the most relevant code is not in the post.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Your code example needs to be _complete_ and _minimal_. The code here only ever updates progress once, at the very end; that seems like as good an answer to your question as anything else.

Comment: Now I think you've gone to far the other way - there is way too much code.  See the article that @PeterDuniho has linked.  Rather than giving us a filtered version of your real code, or your entire code, you should try to create a minimal version that is complete and demonstrates the issue.  Start with a fresh project and start building it slowly by incorporating minimal versions of your current code.  You should eventually figure the issue out.

Comment: I've cleaned up the code, trying to trim down on the exception handling for this post, to hopefully make it a bit more readable.

Comment: How many times is the ProgressChanged event fired? What value do you assign to the ProgressBar? What are the `Minimum` and `Maximum` values of the ProgressBar? No point looking at "solutions" using Invoke, the event is supposed to execute on the UI thread unless someone tried to "fix" something and broke the default behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a classic:

```
Int32 CalculatePercentComplete(Int64 totalFileCount, Int64 numFoldersSearched)
{
  Int32 percentAsInt;
  float searchPercent;

  searchPercent = numFoldersSearched / totalFileCount;
  // searchPercent will be 0.0 here as long as numFoldersSearched < totalFileCount

  ...
}
```

The fact that  `searchPercent` is a `float` does not change that `numFoldersSearched/totalFileCount` is an integer division.

```
5L / 6L == 0L
```

Comment: I can confirm that this was the issue.   searchPercent was always returning 0 to my ReportProgress event.   Integer division was creating the issue here.

Comment: @Matt: then, should you not accept and/or up-vote this answer as useful? Do you need Henk to elaborate, explaining how to perform the calculation correctly (e.g. eliminate the `searchPercent` variable, and just calculate `percentAsInt = 100 * numFoldersSearched / totalFileCount;`)?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem lay in how I was determining the Percent Complete for the Worker's ProgressChanged event.   Below is the final solution:

```
private Int32 CalculatePercentComplete(Int64 totalFileCount, Int64 numFoldersSearched)
    {
        Int32 percentAsInt;
        Decimal searchPercent;

        searchPercent = (Decimal)numFoldersSearched / (Decimal)totalFileCount;

        try
        {
            Decimal x = Math.Round(searchPercent*100, 0, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
            percentAsInt = Convert.ToInt32(x);
        }
        catch (OverflowException oe)
        {
            throw new OverflowException("Error getting percent complete: " + oe.Message, oe);
        }

        if ((percentAsInt < 0) || (percentAsInt > 100))
        {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Invalid percentage: " + percentAsInt);
        }

        return percentAsInt;
    }
```